# How to trim characters from the beginning of a string. Android

Tags: java, android, string, url

I am writing an Android app and need some help.

I have a string that contains a URL. Sometimes I get extra text before the url and need to trim that off.

I get this "Some cool sitehttp://somecoolsite.com"

And want this "http://somecoolsite.com"

First, I need to detect if the string does not start with http:// and then if not, I need to trim everything in front of http://

Is there an easy way to do this?

I can do the first part.

```
if (url.startsWith("http://") == false) {
url.replace("", replacement) 
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Did you think to look at the [Javadoc for String](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html)? It's ... pretty much the same in Java.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't really match the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
if(inputURL.contains("http://")
    inputURL = inputURL.substring(inputURL.indexOf("http://"));
```

Comment: I think I like this better than my answer, though I'd probably get all anal and make a temporary index variable to avoid searching the string twice.

Comment: Worked perfectly Thanks Keyhan!

Answer (score 2):

To check if the string starts with `http://` you do

```
if (inputUrl.startsWith("http://")) {
    ...
}
```

To trim off the prefix up until the first occurrence of `http://` you do

```
int index = inputUrl.indexOf("http://");
if (index != -1)
    inputUrl = inputUrl.substring(index);
```

---

The [API documentation for the `String` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) should provide you with all the information you need here.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be:

```
inputUrl = inputUrl.replaceAll(".*http://","http://");
```

it should work under all conditions (but I assume the regular expression is a bit less efficient).

Answer (score 0):

Please note that provided answers assume that the string will be in lower case (no "HTTP" or "Http") and that no strings contain https://